# How to prove that $A-\frac{1}{3}I_n$ is invertible matrix where $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix consists of all integers?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to prove that $A-\frac{1}{3}I_n$ is invertible matrix where $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix consists of all integers? I'm thinking about proving that the determinant is non-zero but I can't figure out any more to solve. One thing I found is that the main diagonal of this matrix is non-zero.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you are on the right track except the last line. You don't have to consider the entries of $A$.

Comment: $A$ is invertible if and only if $\lambda = 0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$. The eigenvalues of $A-cI$ are equal to $\lambda - c$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. By the rational root theorem, any rational eigenvalue of a matrix with integer coefficients must be an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is too much knowledge involved. If $A-\dfrac{1}{3}I_n$ is
not invertible, consider the eigenvector $X=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)^T \ne 0\in \mathbb{Z}^n$ with $\mathrm{gcd}(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=1$. Then we have $$ AX=\frac{1}{3}X. $$

Here, the existence of $X$ is provided by: if $X\ne 0$ is an eigenvector, then so is $\lambda X$ for any $\lambda$. So we can always divide the gcd.

The left is consisting of integers and that's not true for the right.

Comment: Not just "the eigenvector", but an eigenvector corresponding to $0$; and a bit of argument is needed to argue there is an eigenvector with integer coefficients (better to take $X$ to be a nontrivial solution to $(A-\frac{1}{3}I_n)\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$, as that definitely has rational, hence integer, solutions.

Answer (score 1):

$A - aI$ is not invertible $\implies$ $\det(A-aI) = 0$ $\implies$ $a$ is root of the polynomial $\det(A - xI) = 0$ which is monic integral polynomial in this case. A non integer rational can never be root of a monic integral polynomial. To see that let

$p(x) = x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1x + a_0$

Consider a rational $p/q$ such that $p$ and $q$ are coprime. If this number was root to above equation then

$(p/q)^n + a_{n-1}(p/q)^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1(p/q) + a_0 = 0$

Multiplying by $q^n$ throughout gives you

$p^n + a_{n-1}p^{n-1}q + \ldots + a_1pq^{n-1} + a_0q^n = 0$

But this implies $q\mid p$ which contradicts coprimality of $p$ and $q$. Hence non integer rationals cannot be roots of such polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

working over the ring $\mathbb Z$ with $B:=3A - I$, it suffices to show $\det\big(B\big)\neq 0$ (thus the determinant is a unit, i.e. invertible, when considered over the field $\mathbb Q$, hence $A-\frac{1}{3}I$ is invertible when considered over $\mathbb Q$ as well).

Consider the ring homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb Z\longrightarrow R\cong\mathbb F_3$ and $\Phi:\mathbb Z^{n\times n}\longrightarrow  R^{n\times n}$ which is given by applying $\phi$ component-wise.
$\implies \phi\big(\det(B)\big)= \sum_{\sigma \in \text{Perm(n)}}\phi\big(B_{\sigma(1),1}\big)\phi\big(B_{\sigma(2),2}\big)\dots\phi\big(B_{\sigma(n),n}\big)\cdot \phi\big(\text{sign}(\sigma)\big)$
$ =\det\Big(\Phi(B)\Big)=\det\big(-I\big)\neq 0$
Conclusion: $\det\big(B\big)\%3 \neq 0$ i.e. $\det\big(B\big)\neq 0$

*remark:*
you can also directly observe
$\det\big(B\big)=\sum_{\sigma \in \text{Perm(n)}}B_{\sigma(1),1}\cdot B_{\sigma(2),2}\dots \cdot B_{\sigma(n),n}\cdot \text{sign}(\sigma)$
and the identity permutation is not a multiple of $3$ but every other permutation is a multiple of $3$ hence the sum is not a multiple of $3$ i.e. is not $0$.